# Is it possible that text file be used as input of batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Say I had this in a text file:

> file.txt

Is it possible to import this into a batch file, not just being type on screen but being used as a command? I thought maybe something like this:

```
%input% < file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

this reads the first line from a Textfile into a variable:

```
set /p Input=<file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the "more" command to check the contents of the text file.